# React Native: open base64 image in Email

Tags: image, react-native, base64

I am trying to send a picture in base64 format to email using `Linking.openURL` but in the email, the `base64 string` is not converted to an image and I just see the `base64 string` in the body

```
Linking.openURL(`mailto:receipts@email.com?subject=${subject}&body=${this.props.receipt}`);
```

Is there a way to tell the mail app to interpret it as an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass the image tag in the body:
`mailto:receipts@email.com?subject=${subject}&body=<img alt="receipt" src="${this.props.receipt}">;`